# How to change line in dictation?

Tags: spelling

I am using an ipad, but I assume it is platform independent.
The iPad understands what I say extremely well, as long as I don’t use formal expressions.
I want to change the line and have already tried 提行、回車、新行, all to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to create a newline? 换行 huànháng works.